# C# iterate generic object

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto

Am moving from Excel VBA to VSTO using C#.  In VBA I had a 3 line custom function called `IsInCollection` as shown below:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set obj = collectionObject(itemObject)
IsInCollection = Not (obj is Nothing)
```

I used it all the time to check if a given workbook was open, or if a workbook contained a sheet with a particular name, etc.  Because the collection and the item arguments are defined as objects it would work with anything.

I'm trying to create the same utility function/method in managed code and am struggling mightily.  The problem is with the `collectionObject(itemObject)` expression.  C# doesn't allow me to just index an object as VBA did.

If anybody can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.  From my searching I've been looking into QueryInterface but am not sure if that's where I should be looking.  It seems that an Excel object comes across as a `System._ComObject`, so presumably I need to iterate through that somehow(?).

TIA

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to check out LINQ. for example you can query collections like

```
IsInCollection = obj.Any(s => s != null);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've yet to really wrap my head around LINQ.  I initially though of it as just a kind of "reverse SQL" but I know it's a lot more.  In what you have above, `obj` must be the equivalent of my `collectionObject`, but I'm not sure whether `.Any` or `s` corresponds to my `itemObject`.  I've tried several variations without success.  I think the problem comes down to figuring out how to iterate though a collection passed as an object when it could be a collection of worksheets, or range names, or pivotItems, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The indexing operator in C# is [], not () as in VB. I'm not very familiar with COM though, so if the object you have is just an object/System._ComObject you might have to cast it to the appropriate type first, unless _ComObject has an indexer already.

It seems that finding out what type a _ComObject really is can be be a bit difficult, so you might wanna try a trick I found at http://www.mztools.com/articles/2006/mz2006013.aspx:

```
var typeName = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.TypeName( collectionObject );
```

I also suspect you could use the `System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor` class.

Comment: Also, whatever class it turns out to be would hopefully have a .Contains method which should be easier/neater than trying and failing to access a certain item.

Comment: Thanks.  The `var typename` is a neat trick, but it hasn't helped me in this case.  The problem seems to be that the object could be a collection of workbooks, or range names, or pivotFields, etc.  And I can't find a way in .NET to enumerate through something passed in as an object.  My question was a bit misleading regarding the parentheses - I do know that square brackets are used in C#.  Thanks for the tip regarding the `.Contains` method.  I was actually already using that - after first trying (unsuccessfully!) to cast the object as an array or a List<>.

Comment: Hehe, I was just too lazy to type out "string". Anyway, even if excel returns a collection of different things, I assume it would be some collection class rather than an array. If you could find the correct type I'm sure you could get the cast to work. Have you checked the documentation for the method/property you're using to get the collection?